# My Galaxy J7 keeps shutting down even with 60 to 70 percent battery life. What is the cause?

Tags: stock-android

My galaxy J7 that I bought from China about two months ago keeps shutting down even with 50% of battery life. Can someone please help out. I am depressed about this situation. What can I do to resolve this??

Comment: Replace the battery to start with

Comment: Is it at all related to battery? My Galaxy On7 restarts/switches off now and then because it crashes due to lack of internal storage. Is same the case with your phone?

Comment: You say that it shuts down. How exactly? Does it say that it's shutting down, or does it die out of the blue?

Comment: Yeah.... I mean it just dies suddenly